# Comparing strings in EL

Tags: string, jsp, compare, el

I'm giving a User object to JSP and want to compare an attribute of the user with a given String. What I'm doing right now is the following:

```xml
<input type="radio" name="lang" value="ger" <c:if test="${user.comLanguage.equals("ger")}">checked="yes"</c:if>/>German</br>
```

But all I get is the following Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/library/home.jsp (line: 22, column: 95) equal symbol expected
```

where column 95 is one of the letters of `comLanguage`.

What's the correct syntax here?

Comment: Your initial syntax will by the way work if you're using EL 2.2. and use singlequotes instead of doublequotes inside the method call.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this :

```
<c:if test="${user.comLanguage=='ger'}">
```

Also you can try ternary if:

```
${user.comLanguage=='ger' ? 'checked' : ''}
```

Comment: +1. Or, instead of ==, the eq keyword does the same thing

Comment: Seems like EL uses Java objects but not all its methods. Thank you.