# Should I choose == or eq for comparing string in EL?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, el, websphere-8

`==` and `eq` give the same result using EL to do my string comparison tests:

```
    <c:if test="${person.sokande_i == 'endast_usa'}">Endast USA</c:if>
    <c:if test="${person.sokande_i == 'alla'}">Alla länder</c:if>
    <c:if test="${person.sokande_i == 'alla_utom_usa'}">Alla utom USA</c:if>
```

Should I use `eq` instead? Is `==` for integers only? But it works also for strings. AFAIK `==` test whether hashCodes are equal and `eq` means "meaningfully different".

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355675/comparing-strings-in-el) says `==` and `eq` do the same thing.

Is there no difference here? IS not the difference the one I'm stating: `==` looks at the hashCode and `eq` looks at the implementation of `equals(...)`.

Comment: It says == and 'eq' do the same thing, so they do the same thing.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They're both the same. I use `eq` in EL as it is more readable like a sentence.

Answer (score 29):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html), it's the same thing

> In addition to the . and [] operators discussed in Value and Method Expressions, the EL provides the following operators, which can be used in rvalue expressions only:
> [...]
> **Relational**: **==, eq**, !=, ne, <, lt, >, gt, <=, ge, >=, le. Comparisons can be made against other values or against Boolean, string, integer, or floating-point literals.

One difference though : string operators like `eq, ne, lt, gt, ge, le` exist as they are XML safe, they would not need to be escaped like `<=` for instance.

It's explained [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=550)

> A useful feature of the EL is the ability to perform comparisons, either between numbers or objects. This feature is used primarily for the values of custom tag attributes, but can equally be used to write out the result of a comparison (true or false) to the JSP page. The EL provides the following comparison operators:
>
> • == or eq
> • != or ne
> • < or lt
> • > or gt
> • <= or le
> • >= or ge
>
> The second version of each operator exists to avoid having to use entity references in JSP XML syntax; however, the behavior of the operators is the same.

Answer (score 27):

Both are same. Both `==` and `eq`  will result in the following code:

```
jspContext.findAttribute("person.sokande_i").equals("endast_usa")
```

for EL

```
${person.sokande_i == 'endast_usa'}
```