# JSF EL expression compare string value

Tags: jsf, expression, el

I am trying to evaluate EL expression (method expression?) that returns a value (String) if that value is equal to "bar" then I would like to render the tag.

```
<p:tab rendered="#{bean.getAnswer('foo').answer == "bar"}" />
```

However I get following error message.

```
Invalid location of text ("}") in tag.
```

What would be the right syntax to use?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think I found an answer to myself. Single quote instead of double.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit**: Remove the double quotes arround bar, it's also such a String. You can use `==` also to compare Strings. I preffer `eq` for more readable.

```
<p:tab rendered="#{bar eq bean.getAnswer('foo')}" />

<p:tab rendered="#{bar == bean.getAnswer('foo')}" />
```

All operators can you found here. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

THX @Jasper de Vries

Comment: You **can** use `==`. It is also mentioned in the documentation you referenced. The issue had to do with the quotes

Comment: Still, your answer does not explain what was wrong and what you did to prevent that. Why did you remove the quotes surrounding "bar" and what happened to `.answer`?

Comment: And all this is in some duplicate in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is the use of "" for the value **bar**, as it is conflicting with the outer "".

Have it wrapped inside single quotes, like so ***'bar'***.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

Using 'eq' with String makes it more readable. However, == works too.

Comment: You **can** use `==`. See also [Should I choose == or eq for comparing string in EL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796350/should-i-choose-or-eq-for-comparing-string-in-el).

Comment: Well I didn't say == wouldn't work. Using eq just makes it more readable/applicable when used with Strings. Anyway, got your point! :)