# Issue with IF test on JSF xtml

Tags: if-statement, xhtml, javabeans

sorry i tried a lot of others replies, but still i can't use it:

i want to check the value of a bean in order to print html code or not but all the time i have FALSE condition:

here the code:

```
<tbody>
<ui:repeat value="${wasJvmInvbean.listWasJvmInv()}" var="jvm">
    <tr>
        <td>${jvm.jvmStatus}</td>
        <td>${jvm.cellName}</td>
        <td>${jvm.serverBean.hostname}</td>
        <td>${jvm.jvmName}</td>
        <td>${jvm.type}</td>
        <td>${jvm.profilePath}</td>
        <td>${jvm.wasVersion}</td>

   <c:if test="${jvm.jvmName eq 'dmgr'}">
   <td>webconsole http://xxxx:8080</td>
  </c:if>
    <c:if test="${jvm.jvmName ne 'dmgr'}">
   <td>N.A.</td>
  </c:if>                       
<td>${jvm.fid}</td>
<td>${jvm.heapMin}</td>
<td>${jvm.heapMax}</td>
<td>${jvm.wcDefaultType}</td>
<td>${jvm.wcHost}</td>
<td>${jvm.wcPort}</td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I found also this and tried but nothing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796350/should-i-choose-or-eq-for-comparing-string-in-el

Comment: <c:if test="${jvm.jvmName == 'dmgr'}">this is dmgr</c:if> 
no output but the jvm.jvmName is valorizied JVM Name: dmgr

Comment: FIXED following this as example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248439/specify-conditional-rendering-of-element-inside-uirepeat-the-cif-does-not

new code is
             <td>
<h:outputLink value = "https://${jvm.serverBean.hostname}:${jvm.wcPort}/ibm/console" rendered="#{jvm.type eq 'DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER'}" target="_blank" >sffsd</h:outputLink> 

</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED following this as [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248439/) … new code is

```
 <h:outputLink value = "https://${jvm.serverBean.hostname}:${jvm.wcPort}/ibm/console" rendered="#{jvm.type eq 'DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER'}" target="_blank" >sffsd</h:outputLink>
```